# updating data on first tab based on bundle info which is sent from the third tab by clicking on list item of third tab in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

1. Current situation :  I have three tab, tab1, tab2, tab3 created
   using FragmentActivity. I have three fragment class for each of them, and each of them display listview item in content. When i click on some item from the tab3, i want to change the data of tab1 based on some inputs from the item clicked. I have tried below code

   ```
   FragmentActivityDaily myDetailFragment = new FragmentActivityDaily();
           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           bundle.putString("KEY_DETAIL", "Hi");
           myDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.pager, myDetailFragment);
           fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
           fragmentTransaction.commit();
   ```
2. With above code i am able to change the data and get bundle info
   thorugh getArguement, but i am not able to view it as
       the tab selected is still the tab3

   ```
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab1);
   ```
3. if i use above line then it reloads the fragment activty again
   overriding the data which i have changed though the above code.
4. Question: if i use the fragmentTransaction code then how to set the
   tab to tab1.
                   or
   if i set the tab using setCurrentItem, then how do i change the data of tab1 by sending budle info from tab3.

I hope i am able to explain the issue... if yes then please give me some solution as i have searched alot on this one..if its not clear then please let me know i will post the full code as well.

Thanks*

Comment: Is the data just a key value pair ? If yes, how about using SharedPreferences. You could set the value in the preferences in tab3; once this is done, you could call the setCurrentItem(tab1) method and in the code of tab1 you could retrieve this value from the SharedPreferences.

Comment: You can say the data is key value pair, but its dynamic based on the listview item of tab3, my problem is if i am using setCurrentItem(tab1) then it goes to the onCreateview method where i have written the logic for displaying data when the tab1 load but i dont want that. I want another set of data based on input from the tab3 to be displayed on tab1